# What should the value of a script tag's crossorigin attribute be?

Tags: html, cors

If I have a `script` tag with a cross-domain `src` and I want to access errors from `window.onerror`, I need to add the `crossorigin` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="otherdomain.com/foo.js" crossorigin="..."></script>
```

My question is, what should the attribute's value be? Does it matter? Does it even need a value?

I've seen a few people using the value `"anonymous"`, but I can't find a proper explanation as to why. [This blog post](http://blog.errorception.com/2012/12/catching-cross-domain-js-errors.html) notes mysteriously that it is the "most secure value".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes

Comment: @Ian Thanks, that's exactly the documentation I was looking for.